# phpword send generated doc to frontend

Tags: javascript, php, phpword

I am trying to generate docFiles on my webapp. First i was thinking of using some tool in the Frontend like Markswindolls 'jquery.wordexport.js' tool. But since there are not much functions like setting Header or Footer or aligning, I started to work with 'phpword'.

My Problem now is, that the docFile is saved on the server. Is there any possibility of sending the file via ajax to the Frontend so the User can get the File after pushing on my 'download as .doc' button?

Any other recommendations are welcome too.

jquery:

```
$('#word-button').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phpWORD/gendocx.php",

    success: function (msg, string, jpXHR) {
        console.log('AJAX SUCCESS');
    },
    complete : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log('AJAX COMPLETE');
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
});
})
```

gendocx.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPWord.php';

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// Create a new PHPWord Object
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// Every element you want to append to the word document is placed in a section. So you need a section:
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// After creating a section, you can append elements:
$section->addText('Hello world!');

// You can directly style your text by giving the addText function an array:
$section->addText('Hello world! I am formatted.', array('name'=>'Tahoma', 'size'=>16, 'bold'=>true));

// If you often need the same style again you can create a user defined style to the word document
// and give the addText function the name of the style:
$PHPWord->addFontStyle('myOwnStyle', array('name'=>'Verdana', 'size'=>14, 'color'=>'1B2232'));
$section->addText('Hello world! I am formatted by a user defined style', 'myOwnStyle');


// You can also putthe appended element to local object an call functions like this:
$myTextElement = $section->addText('Hello me!');

// At least write the document to webspace:
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');

$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for PHP Excel, sorry about fragmentation, but this is from a large service file:

```
$this->generateXls();
$this->writeToVariable();
if ($response instanceof Response) {
    $this->setHeaders($response->getHeaders());
}
$response->setContent($this->getXlsContent());
```

This is where the file content is stored to a variable instead of a file:

```
protected function writeToVariable()
{
    ob_start();
    $this->getWriter()->save('php://output');
    $xlsContent = ob_get_clean();
    $this->setXlsContent($xlsContent);
}
```

And just set the headers before returning your response

```
protected function setHeaders(Headers $headers)
{
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', $this->getFileMimeType());
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"{$this->getFullFileName()}\"");
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', strlen($this->getXlsContent()));
}
```

This is done in zf2 so headers are injected in to response object but in your case just add them to whatever generates your output.

Oh, btw, mime type for excel looks like this:

```
$this->setFileMimeType('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

So try to find the one for the ms word format you want to output, that is in this format.

For a simplified non-OO approch:

```
$writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->getWorkbook(), $type);
//<---GENERATE YOUR DOCUMENT HERE
ob_start();
$writer->save('php://output');
$document = ob_get_clean();
//<---SET OUTPUT HEADERS LIKE FOR ANY OTHER FILE TYPE HERE
echo $document;
die;
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response. I am new to this, so I dont know really where to begin or solve it like you did.

Comment: Hi, your goal it to save the document to a php output stream instead of a file and then capture that stream in to a variable. I have updated the answer with a simplified version